# How to get coordinates of QToolBar icons in PyQt4 application?

Tags: python, pyqt4, qtoolbar

I'd like to know how to set position of QCalendarWidget just below the button of ToolBar.

Currently, when user clicks a icon button inside red box, 
[image]

then the below Calendar() instance is created and the instance is shown in the middle of screen.

[image]

What I want to implement is like the following.

[image]

You can refer full source code from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36604469/how-to-get-mouse-event-and-coordinates-of-matplotlib-graph-in-pyqt4-application).

Any suggestion or advice will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This functionality is already provided by `QDateTimeEdit`, so you don't need a separate button for it:

```
    def init_toolbar(self):
        ...
        dtedit = QtGui.QDateTimeEdit()
        dtedit.setCalendarPopup(True)
```

Qt Docs: [QDateTimeEdit.setCalendarPopup](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qdatetimeedit.html#calendarPopup-prop).

Comment: Thank you! The method you introduced is what I want.

Answer (score 1):

This is usually done with a combination of using `QWidget.geometry()` or `QWidget.rect()` to get the size and position of a widget (in this case, the clicked button) and then using the `QWidget.mapFromXXX` and `QWidget.mapToXXX` series of functions, to transform those into global coordinates and then into widget coordinates that can be fed to `QWidget.move()`